# PlayMagicForJava error in Play! Framework application?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.1

Hello Every one I am new in Play Frame work and i want to connect mysql to the my application i did all configuration but when i run my application the i get following error :

my Error:

```
object PlayMagicForJava is not a member of package play.core.j
In /home/trainee02/simmant/playproject/cms/app/views/main.scala.html at line 0.
```

my Model class:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import play.*;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
@Entity 
public class Entry extends Model{

    @Id 
    public Long id;


    public String name;
    public static Model.Finder<Long, Entry> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Entry>(Long.class, Entry.class);
}
```

my database configuration:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cmsdata?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=root
```

Thanx in advance

---

thanx munguillermin for answer my question

my Build.scala is:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "collegecms"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  )

}
```

but i am confuse what is error in my Build.scala can you please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
// Add your project dependencies here,
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
jdbc,
javaCore,
 javaEbean
```

)

try this please and do :

```
 play update reload compile
```

and then run the application

Answer (score 1):

`PlayMagicForJava` is part of the `play-java` module.

If you have this error, that's probably because you don't have the dependency on the `javaCore` module in your `Build.scala` file :

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  jdbc,
  javaCore,
  javaEbean,
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Thanx Every one who answer on my question i just following changes in my configuration and my Build.scala and i get what i want .

my application.conf

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/regis"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=root

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
ebean.default="models.*"
```

my Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "studata"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
   "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
    )

}
```

in the above configuration i did some changes and my code is working now thank you sir mguillermin for your kind help you answer help me a lot and sir cyril thank you so much for your answer i change all thing and i type that command then my code is been able to work properly.